# pre_get_posts - editing query, tax_query

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts

I am attempting to filter results based on what the user has inputted.

```
function custom_archive() {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'profiles' ) ) {
        // if we are on a profiles archive page, edit the query according to the posted data.
        $data = $_POST['networks'];

        if ( isset( $data ) ) {
            //count the array
            if ( count( $data ) > 1 ) {
                $data = implode( ',', $data );
            } else {
                //$data = $data[0];
            }    

            //set the query to only search for whatever the user wants, eg news
            $wp_query->set( 'tax_query', array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'networks',
                    'field'    => 'id',
                    'terms'    => $data,
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ),
            ) );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_archive' );
```

I have debugged my code and the data get's inputted correctly. Although, I get no posts back.

Are there any problems with this code? I believe the error may be elsewhere in my theme, but I do wish to check out this code so I can take it out of the equation. Cheers!

**EDIT:** One thing I should mention is that I have a version of this code working for my Blog page. I am trying to now get this code working for an archive, and for it to return the correct posts still within the archive page, but instead it redirects me to a Search page.

Comment: How does `$_POST['networks']` get set? Do you have a form? Is it a select field or multi-select field? Are the values IDs or slugs?

Comment: Yes, I have a form. The values of the checkboxes are IDs. It's a multi-select field - hence why I validate if `$data` is an array (to comma-separate it).

Answer (score 1):

So there's a few things wrong with the code:

1. You're not using the query object that's passed to the pre_get_posts hook, so you're not modifying the actual query.
2. Field is set to `id` instead of `term_id`.
3. If you're using `IN` as the operator, pass an array to terms.
4. You're not sanitizing the value of $_POST['networks']. You *might* be ok without it, since WordPress shouldn't let anything too nasty happen, but it's a good idea to at least ensure that the values are the correct type.

This version of the function addresses these issues:

```
function my_query_by_selected_networks( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_post_type_archive( 'profiles' ) ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['networks'] ) ) {
            if ( is_array( $_POST['networks'] ) ) {
                $networks = array_map( 'intval', $_POST['networks'])
            } else {
                $networks = array( intval( $_POST['networks'] ) );
            }

            $tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query' ) ?: array();

            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'networks',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $networks,
                'operator' => 'IN',
            );

            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_query_by_selected_networks' );
```

Note:

1. The function accepts the `$query` variable and uses that the update the query.
2. It uses `term_id` as the value for `field`.
3. `$networks`, the value passed to the tax query is left as an array, or made an array if `$_POST['networks']` isn't already an array.
4. It sanitizes the value of `$_POST['networks']` with `intval`, making sure that `$networks` is an array of integers, which is what the tax query expects.

Additionally, I modified the tax_query code so that it doesn't entirely replace any tax queries that could be made by other plugins. It does this by checking if there's already a tax query and adding on to it if there is. This is probably unnecessary, but it's a habit of mine.

**EDIT:** As per Tom's suggestion I've added in `$query->is_main_query()`, to make sure that we're only modifying the main loop, so this doesn't go and affect things like widgets and menus etc. I also added a bit at the top to bail if we're in the admin, since we don't want to modify back-end queries.

Also, `custom_archive` is a very generic name for a function, and could easily be shared by other plugins or WordPress itself. It's a good idea to be more descriptive, but most importantly, you should prefix functions with something unique to your theme or plugin to avoid conflicts. In my example it's just `my_`. I suggest replacing it, since `my_` is a common example prefix.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote if you throw in an `$query->is_main_query()` check, bonus points if you mention the super generic function name and adding a prefix

Answer (score 0):

You should provide an array of id's to the tax_query - like here in the example from the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters):

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'actor',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    ),
```

So you could and should sanitize the values from `$_POST['networks']` but shouldn't do implode which turns the array into a flat string.

Comment: Thank you for your help - although, this solution never worked in my case. I have changed my question by adding more information.

Comment: I would note that you should always query for what you want, querying for what you do not want is slow/expensive and involves full table scans